# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageButton

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, runtime-error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.chinnachary.ccflash, PID: 7713
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chinnachary.ccflash/com.example.chinnachary.ccflash.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageButton
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2560)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageButton
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                      at com.example.chinnachary.ccflash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766) 
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageButton
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.chinnachary.ccflash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060062
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1552)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
                      at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:78)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:68)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:201)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:121)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.chinnachary.ccflash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7713 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: can you post code?

Comment: Post your `ImageButton.java`, you have an exception in this class that prevents from the layout to inflate properly..

Comment: send you xml filw which had issue.

Comment: `at com.example.chinnachary.ccflash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)`     ...   `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060062`

Comment: @HedShafran `ImageButton.java` is an sdk class. The problem is not there

Comment: So at list post the xml and the Activity

Comment: try to extend Activity instead appcompatactivity

Answer (score 2):

It says here

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060062
```

the view with this ID not found in your current layout. Probably you are trying to inflate view that is hosted in different layout.

I got this error when I tried to inflate a `view` from`activity_main.xml` inside `activity_orders.java`

Comment: Issue can also happen with missing style parameters which is not properly handled (especially if there are multiple themes).

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Ciboffon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/off"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
</RelativeLayout>